# Server Side Event not firing in Jersey 2.8 using SSE

Tags: java, web-services, server-sent-events, jersey-2.0

I am trying with a sample example given in the official documentation of Jersey SSE

Refer " 14.5.2. Asynchronous SSE processing with EventSource " in the below link
https://jersey.github.io/documentation/2.8/user-guide.html#example-simple-sse

My Code is as below

Client code -

```
  public class ClientSSEEventManager {
        public void WaitForEvents() {
            // Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
            // .register(SseFeature.class).build();
            // WebTarget target =
            // client.target("http://localhost:8080/server/events");
            //
            // EventInput eventInput = target.request().get(EventInput.class);
            // while (!eventInput.isClosed()) {
            // final InboundEvent inboundEvent = eventInput.read();
            // if (inboundEvent == null) {
            // // connection has been closed
            // break;
            // }
            // System.out.println(inboundEvent.getName() + "; "
            // + inboundEvent.readData(String.class));
            // }

            Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(SseFeature.class)
                    .build();
            WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/server/events");
            EventSource eventSource = EventSource.target(target).build();
            EventListener listener = new EventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(InboundEvent inboundEvent) {
                    System.out.println(inboundEvent.getName() + "; "
                            + inboundEvent.readData(String.class));
                }
            };
            eventSource.register(listener, "message-to-client");
            eventSource.open();
        }
    }

public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication(){
     super(ClientSSEEventManager.class, SseFeature.class);
    }
//   Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>() {
//          /**
//       * 
//       */
//      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
//
//          { add(ClientSSEEventManager.class);
//          }};
//
//      @Override
//      public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
//          return classes;
//      }

}
```

Then in one of the action method, I am just initialising the event listening as follows

```
//Start listening to event from server
     ClientSSEEventManager clientSSEEventManager = new                      ClientSSEEventManager();
clientSSEEventManager.WaitForEvents();
///
```

Client's Web.xml has init-param as follow

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
    <param-value>com.framework.MyApplication</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Server Code -

```
@Path("events")
public class ServerSSEServerEventManager {
    @GET
    @Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public EventOutput getNotificationEvents(){
         final EventOutput eventOutput = new EventOutput();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                            // ... code that waits 1 second
                            final OutboundEvent.Builder eventBuilder
                            = new OutboundEvent.Builder();
                            eventBuilder.name("message-to-client");
                            eventBuilder.data(String.class,
                                "Hello world " + i + "!");
                            final OutboundEvent event = eventBuilder.build();
                            eventOutput.write(event);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(
                            "Error when writing the event.", e);
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            eventOutput.close();
                        } catch (IOException ioClose) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(
                                "Error when closing the event output.", ioClose);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();
            return eventOutput;
    }
}
```

Expected output at client side is as follows

```
message-to-client; Hello world 0!
message-to-client; Hello world 1!
message-to-client; Hello world 2!
message-to-client; Hello world 3!
message-to-client; Hello world 4!
message-to-client; Hello world 5!
message-to-client; Hello world 6!
message-to-client; Hello world 7!
message-to-client; Hello world 8!
message-to-client; Hello world 9!
```

But nothing is printing at client side.
Am I missing something over here ?
I have a doubt, the client.Target , it should have "http://:8080/server/events" ? OR it should be just "http://:8080/events"

Comment: Your server URL is dependent on the `Context Path` of your application. If you deploy as `server` then your path should be `http://localhost:8080/server/events`. I would put some logging in on your server side and add the Jackson logging filter to your client `client.register(new LoggingFilter(LOG, true));` so you can see what you client is sending / receiving.

Comment: If I open the url directly in browser like http://<serverip:8080>/server/events then server side getNotificationEvents method will be called. but the same thing if I do through by running the client application as shown in the above code, server side getNotificationEvents is not getting called.

Comment: Ok, looking at your client code, you're setting up the event handler but you're never issuing your GET request.

Comment: @Baldy when we open connection, isn't it nothing but issuing the GET request ? can you please update me the code snippet on what change I have to do ??

Comment: Also in the above sample, server responds immediately to the client, but actually server should push the event whenever something changed at server side. so how server can push the event ? where and what code I have to add for this ?

Comment: hi @Sadanand did you ever find the answer for this? i am experiencing similar problems as detailed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30917568/jersey-sse-client-not-receiving-anything-from-server-thread

Answer (score 1):

SSE worked fine for me finally.
there are couple of things we need to do

1. SSE listener in Springs

   ```
     @Singleton
        @Path("/events")
        public class NotificationHandler {
            @Path("/register/{userName}")
        @Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
        @GET
        public @ResponseBody EventOutput registerForAnEventSummary(
               @PathParam("userName") String userName) {
           }
        }
   ```
2. Call a service that make a call to notify all clients

   ```
    PostMethod postMethod = null;
           postMethod = new PostMethod(
                   resourceBundle.getString("localhost:8080")
                           + resourceBundle.getString("applicationnotifier")
                           + resourceBundle
                                   .getString("sse/events/broadcast/"));
   ```
3. A broadcaster

   ```
    @Path("/broadcast")
       @POST
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
       public String broadcastNotifications(@FormParam("message") String message) { }
   ```
4. Javascript - listen to all SSE events by registering

   ```
    var notificationBaseURL =  ""; //The URL Where your services are hosted
    function listenAllEvents() {
        if ( (EventSource) !== "undefined") {

       var source = new EventSource(
       notificationBaseURL+"applicationnotifier/sse/events/register/"+loggedInUserName);
       source.onmessage = notifyEvent;
   } else {
       console.log("Sorry no event data sent - ");
       }
    }

    function notifyEvent(event) {
       var responseJson = JSON.parse(event.data);
       alert("... Notification Received ...");
    }
   ```